# htaccess to display only the last part of the url and trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess

We are using the following two lines

```
RewriteRule (.+?)/(.+?)\.php  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.+?)/(.+?)\.html http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2.html? [L,R=301]
```

This is to redirect some erroneous URL in the form of

```
www.site.com/something/page.php
www.site.com/something/page.php?a=b
www.site.com/something/page.html
```

As a test it looks to be working but I got some error in analytics wherein for some url it shows it was called like           /?a=b. I do not understand when this can appear.

Secondly I have existing folders like          admin/login.php. When I use the above code , obviously this url is redirected as            login.php which I dont want. Is there a way to bi-pass this for 3 folders admin, t4, t5. I am in a real urgency as I need to correct the indexing issue. Could you please help..

Similar adjustment I need for the second rewrite statement as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip these 3 folders
RewriteRule ^(admin|t4|t5)(/|$) - [L,NC]

# existing rules
RewriteRule (.+?)/(.+?)\.php /$2.php [L,R=301]

RewriteRule (.+?)/(.+?)\.html /$2.html? [L,R=301]

# redirect /?a=b to /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you.. I will test and confirm if it works. But do you know when the url can turn to  /?a=b as an example /a.php?id=123. Please help me if you can

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by `when the url can turn to /?a=b as an example /a.php?id=123.`

Comment: after implementing this rules I see one of my url www.site.com/a.php?b=3 becomes www.site.com/?b=3 . This is wrong and creates duplicates of home page. I do not understand how can this get created

Comment: But I don't change anything in your existing rules. You can keep your present rules. Just place the new rules to skip directories before your present rules.

Comment: Yes I know that you have not changed anything. My code has an issue , I think. I wanted actually if you could review this for the mentioned issue as I am not able to figure out what the issue is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: could you also give me another line of code to fix calling home page with parameter. currently www.site.com/?a=b is possible. As a result, duplicate of home page gets created. Can you give me a line of code so that when such a URL is called it always redirects to www.site.com. This will be also able to fix the previous error.